Finding the joint probability of a transformed standard normal
$(X, Y)$ follows a standard bivariate normal distribution with $-1<\rho<1$. Let $A = X + Y$ and $B = XY$. Find the conditional probability of $P(A > 0|B>0)$.

Since $A$ follows standard normal and $B$ follows chi square with 1 degree of freedom, I can't use bivariate normal distribution. My professor hinted me that there's an easy way to find the joint PDF, but I still can't see it. Any ideas?

Neither of the claims you have made about the distributions of $A$ and $B$ are true. $A$ is not a standard nomal because its variance is not 1, and $B$ cannot follow a chi-squared distribution because there is a nonzero probability that $B$ is negative, whereas a chi-squared distribution is always positive.

What is meant by $\rho$?

@Julius I forgot to mention that it follows a 'standard bivariate normal'. Isn't $A$ follows a standard normal because $X$ and $Y$ is also standard normal?

@LSK21 Sorry, it meant the correlation between X and Y

@epickid $A$ follows a normal distribution, but it is not standard (i.e. its variance is not $1$. A computation shows that $\text{Var(A)} = 2(1+\rho)$, which is only equal to $1$ if $\rho = -1/2$.

@Julius Just checked my notes, and you are right they are normal but not standard. However for chi square it is defined as square of standard normal, so since $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal is it ok to assume that they follow a chi square?

@epickid $B$ is not the square of a standard normal, but rather the product of two different standard normals-- thus, it is not a chi-squared random variable. $X^2$ and $Y^2$ would be chi-squareds, but $XY$ isn't.

@Julius I see, sorry for the misconceptions.

Observe that $(X,Y)\sim (-X,-Y)$ since both have the same correlation coefficient, are Gaussian and $X$ and $Y$ are standard.
If $E=\{X>0\}\cap\{Y>0\}$ and $F=\{X<0\}\cap\{Y<0\}$ we have  therefore $\Pr(E)=\Pr(F).$ Finally
$$\Pr(X+Y>0|E\cup F)=\Pr(X+Y>0 \cap(E\cup F))/\Pr(E\cup  F)=\Pr(E)/(\Pr(E)+\Pr(F))=1/2.$$

Thanks for your answer, but I don't get how you get $P(E)/(P(E) + P(F)) = 1/2$. Can you explain further?

Because I began by showing  $\Pr(E)=\Pr(F)$ which was the important thing to do.

yeah, but I fail to understand why $P(E) = 1$ and $(P(E) + P(F)) = 2$

me too..................................................

$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ do not imply $a=c$

After a long look I think I got it now. Thanks
